# JPA Joined and single table discrimination hierarchy

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to model the below structure using JPA discrimination.

Below is my entity diagram

[image]

User has one to many relationship with EMPLOYEE & INTERN tables. One user id can have multiple employee records mapped. Discrimination is based on *type*.

EMPLOYEE should contain SINGLE_TABLE discrimination based on *salary_type* (primary/secondary)

INTERN is a plain table without any hierarchy.

I tried below approach

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 20)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User {
......
}



@MappedSuperclass
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 20)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class EmployeeBase extends User{
......
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
@DiscriminatorValue("primary")
public class PrimaryLocation extends EmployeeBase {
......
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
@DiscriminatorValue("secondary")
public class SecondaryLocation extends EmployeeBase {
......
}
```

Now with the above approach I am not able to get the one to many relationship.

```
userRepository.findById();
```

This should return User and list of Employee or Interns based on the mapped id.

Comment: JPA DiscriminatorColumn and Inheritance are for use with Java inheritance, but you haven't shown any classes extending from these classes. EmployeeBase is a mapped superclass without its own table, and while PrimaryLocation and SecondaryLocation seem to be attempting to use the same Employee table, both are completely independent of everything else. Why wouldn't the primary/secondary classes not just use a single 'location' and 'salary' column within the employee table? See https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Inheritance though there are many.

Comment: @Chris Yeah I missed it in the question. I have edited how the inheritance is structured.

Comment: Discriminator column/value is only relevant for single table (inh. strat.)...

Comment: And your model is (little) more complex than depicted.. ;)

Comment: Something else extends User? (Otherwise you should not `EmployeeBase` at all)

Comment: "Joined"-article: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-entity-inheritance-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: "single table"-article: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-the-single_table-inheritance-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: My favorite: "5. You don't need inheritance. Especially not entity inheritance." https://twitter.com/lukaseder/status/870200257849806848 

Comment: Join columns are part of the JPA spec for Single and joined table inheritance - hibernate may not require them for joined, but it is certainly the only way something like this can work: The leaf subclasses will need a type that gets put into the user table's type field. Type needs to (or should) be known upfront as there is no way to tell what instances to build; Hibernate went the same approach as "inferior" providers in using the type as well as writing it with https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6911 . @eshwar I don't think you can use a different salary type the way you want

Comment: You'll need to explain what you mean with " I am not able to get the one to many relationship" as you haven't shown one. That said, MappedSuperclasses don't have tables, so cannot take part in JPA inheritance. For EmployeeBase: Remove the mappedSuperclass from it, add Table(name = "EMPLOYEE") to it and then make it abstract. You then don't need to duplicate the Table(name = "EMPLOYEE") annotations in the PrimaryLocation and SecondaryLocation classes.  If this doesn't help, you'll also